# How do I ruby-debug in a spec or feature if I am using Guard and Spork?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, guard, spork

I managed to get Cucumber, RSpec, Guard, and Spork play nicely with each other in a Rails 3 app, but now I am stuck with the above problem.

Currently I `require 'spork/ext/ruby-debug'` in the prefork block of `spec_helper.rb` but this works only if I run spork manually, without guard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me: Replace your 'guard-spork' gem with this one:

```
gem 'guard-spork', :git => 'https://github.com/irohiroki/guard-spork.git'
```

More info on [this blog post](http://irohiroki.com/2011/02/08/autotest-guard-spork-and-ruby-debug) (in Japanese, but Google translate does a decent job).

The author also created this [handy Rails 3 example app](https://github.com/irohiroki/guard-spork-ruby-debug-sample) to show how to set things up.

Adding Guard to Spork makes it much more useful IMO. I may have to go back to using it now :)

Comment: Now, trying to get cucumber to play nicely with nested folders. It feels like the final step of the puzzle. This almost works: https://gist.github.com/822965

Answer (score 0):

If you still have problems (or even if you don't,) I would recommend using the [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry/) and [pry-nav](https://github.com/nixme/pry-nav) gems instead of Ruby debug.. they work flawlessly with guard/spork/rspec/cucumber and test unit.